# Oracle Apex: Interactive Grid - ORA-01400

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table / IG where the primary key is populated via sequence in "before insert" trigger. When I want to create a new row, I get ORA-01400 that null value can't be populated to the field.

To be honest I checked with that sample application and all the settings / attributes seem to be set in the same way; ID field is marked as primary column and is hidden, process seems fine too. When I insert data manually to the table and then update/delete process is processing rows correctly.

Type: Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML
(Settings) -> Target Type = Region Source
Prevent Lost Updates, Lock Row and Return Primary Key after Insert are set to Yes
Editable Region is my Interactive Grid Region
Apex version is 5.1

I tried to manually process the Interactive Grid data using PL/SQL. Unfortuantely the update with the rowid doesn't seem to work.

Given Help by APEX. [image]

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there's a **validation** which says that the primary key column must not be NULL. If so, *disable* (by setting a condition to "Never") or remove it and then try again.

Apparently, validations *fire* before database triggers and raise an error.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I disabled the validation and the insert worked. Now when I try to update a row I get the error message: ORA-01403: No Data found. Any suggestion on how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As of NO_DATA_FOUND: enable debug mode, run the page, view debug info - it'll show you which query failed; then you'll be able to fix it (hopefully).

Comment: Now another problem occurs. The ID which is populated by the trigger doesn't appear in the other rows. The Column ID remains null (-). How do I get to populate the created ID to the other rows. Many thanks.

Comment: In a *tabular form* (or, its improvement - *interactive grid*) - one row = one ID. There's no sense in sharing the same ID for several rows, is it? If you want to do that anyway, then - I believe - you should get rid of the database trigger and create a process in Apex which selects ID value at the beginning, and then - in a loop - sets the same ID to all rows. Keyword here is "apex_application.g_f01" array. That's rather complex, when compared to default Apex processing.

Comment: As I know the "apex_application.g_f01" array has been replaced by using PL/SQL (see above Picture). Any suggestion on how to implemt this? I am struggling with the rowid. Thanks.

Comment: Well, example you posted contains a reference to :ROWID. From my point of view: Interactive Grid looks pretty, but works *shitty* (pardon my French). On 5.1.1 I've had issues with deleting rows (marked one row, another one got deleted), a region is stretched too far to the right (so you have to modify length of all columns), so - when I have to create a "tabular form", I rather choose *legacy page* and create the oldfashioned *tabular form*, not an interactive grid. Perhaps they have fixed those issues in later versions, but we are still on 5.1.1. So ... I'm afraid I can't help much.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that primary key for your table is ID, if you use the example process from apex help, there is update and delete bounded to :ROWID - Here can be the problem with no data found.

I solved once saving and other row actions on grid, by debugging it with simple error message, that showed me actual values that i pass into the process.

Use this code into very beginning of your code, and you will see what you pass into process. It may help you to find where is the problem.

```
apex_error.add_error ( p_message => 'ENAME: ' ||:ENAME ||
                                  ' ,DEPTNO: '||:DEPTNO||
                                    'etc...'
                     , p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
```

As well do not forget to check columns if you did not set them to QUERY ONLY = YES - this columns cannot be used in process.
I hope it will be useful, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Might I make a recommendation
In my experience you have two options that ought to work that I use.
Make a process that goes before your save, so set its sequence to a lower number. And that process checks if :ID is null and if it is, it populates it.
or you could just populate the ID during the create process. In the CASE C insert into ID value ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL if you are populating the ID using a sequence, or you could just define its value before you start the CASE stuff.

I hope this helps